# How to Stack mysql query results to select one row after the other

Tags: php, mysql, database

please how can i query the database table one row at a time without repeating the same row until all the rows has been selected.

E.g

I want the query to select the first row the first time and second row the second until all the rows is selected. Note i don't want to use random selection has result may repeat itself.

Thank you in advance

Comment: This isn't how queries usually work.  Typically, you select a batch of records of a certain size, and then perhaps paginate/loop over that.  Hitting the database one record at a time is not advisable.

Comment: you simply dont; one query at a time is probably not consistent as there might be other operations interfering; so better query once for all rows and iterate them with `foreach`; you'll find sufficient examples in the manual. also you should at leats try to solve your problem before asking and provide code that is clarifying the problem.

Comment: Okay guys, this is it, I am writing an API that returns an Advert placement results to different website, I don't want to use random selections. I want to make sure that all the advert are displayed on the various website. Note: the result returns one advert a time on a particular website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql` has an OFFSET option that will work perfectly for what you want to (not that i understand why you are doing what you want to do) do. eg

```
$offset = 0;
$query = 'SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 1 OFFSET='. $offset;
$offset++;
$query = 'SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 1 OFFSET='. $offset;//offset is now 1
$offset++;
$query = 'SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 1 OFFSET='. $offset;//offset is now 2
```

I think in your case you would chuck it in a loop. I'm just showing it as above to illustrate the concept. Or maybe you will pass $offset as a parameter. Either way this should give you a good idea

What does offset do? It basically ignores the records before the offset count. so if i have records `1,2,3,4,5` and I select from this list with an offset of 2 I will get `3,4,5` as my list.

[W3 Will explain it better than me](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp)

**So this question is regarding an API request and response**

Your response to the first api request should contain last_offset. Tell your consumer to pass offset as a parameter on their request. `my.api.com?offset=1` after validation and sanitation of the parameter offset, you can include the value in your query else use default offset of 0

If they received last_offset=2 in the last response they should be passing offset=3 on the next request.

Comment: I am writing an API that return an Advert placement results to different website, I don't want to use random selections. I want to make sure that all the advert are displayed on the various website. Note: the result returns one advert a time on a particular website.

Comment: Can i ask why it must return 1 at a time? If I was a consumer of your API I would want all ads in one request

Comment: Okay, this is my first time of writing such an API, what do you think is the best way of doing it?

Comment: @idlatest I have updated my answer with one method of doing this (based on your idea). But if it was me i would want an endpoint `/getAds` which returns all the ads. Then its up to me as a consumer of your API to loop through the ads and display them how i want.

Comment: Thanks man you really helped a brother.

Answer (score 0):

One way is make the primary key of the table a sequence of numbers starting from an arbitrary number.
Get hold of the starting index.
While writing the sql query,just write a loop and make the where=id + 1.This will give you each row at a time.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.